# `fontspec` repeatedly (and cumulatively) turns on font feature

Tags: fontspec, opentype

I use an OpenType font which has the `tnum` feature and I want to make a tabular using nice monospaced numbers, in this way:

```tex
\def\tabnumbers{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\tabnumbers}r}
Name & Value\\
One & 1\\
Ten & 10\\
Eleven & 11\\
\end{tabular}
```

This inserts the font feature `{Numbers=Monospaced}` before each numeric entry, as needed. *However*, it does so repeatedly: by the third line, `fontspec` is now creating a third font family, with the features `{Numbers=Monospaced,Numbers=Monospaced,Numbers=Monospaced}`.

In a real-life example, this makes compilation extremely slow. How could I disable this repeated font-feature-adding? I tried some simple workarounds such as `\def\tabnumbers{\rmfamily \addfontfeature{Numbers=Monospaced}}` but the result was the same.

I could probably define a whole new font family just for that one
feature and invoke it in the number columns, but that would make the
whole setup dependent on which font is current when `\begin{tabular}` is
called...
I would also like to use `\tabnumbers` in other appropriate contexts,
e.g. in the table of matters and version history, so I would prefer a
simple macro to modifying too much the tabular setup.

Comment: `>` gets executed in every cell, just do it once before the table (it's a global property anyway)

Comment: create a proper font family and don't use \addfontfeatures.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I could call it once before the table, but then (1) it will still be executed once per table (and I might have a lot of those!), and (2) it will apply to the whole table, where some columns could have a need for variable-width numbers (which is the reason why I put it in `>` in the first place). Reason (2) also explains why calling it at preamble is not desirable. @UlrikeFischer: I believe I explained why this is not a good solution. This is analogous to, if say `\textbf` were buggy, just creating a new font family for the bold version of each font.

Comment: but it's the same as classic tex, you can't localise changes to the font metrics to a group, any change to fontdimen parameters affects the font globally from then on, and this is pretty much the same.

Comment: sorry but with \addfontfeature you are not using the equivalent of \textbf. If you want a new "font shape" (in which e.g. numbers are monospaced) you should declare it in the preamble and not on the fly. What exactly you should do depends on your overall font setup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How do you know and how do you check that `fontspec` adds these features multiple times? If I look into the log I can only find two font families being created, one without and one with `Numbers=Monospaced`.